# MVC EditorFor dyanmic insert

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editorformodel

I want to make a javascript that can dynamic insert a new "EditorFor" model, but i am having 2 problem.

1: i keep html encoding the string, and i can't figure out how to stop it.

2: How can i tell it what model to use instead of having a instance of it in my model

I have tryed the following but it dose not work :(

```
MvcHtmlString emodel = Html.EditorFor(model => new Cosplay.Models.Projects.CreatePartModel(), "CreatePartModel", "Parts[NAMEREPLACE]");
MvcHtmlString emodel = Html.EditorFor(model => Cosplay.Models.Projects.CreatePartModel, "CreatePartModel", "Parts[NAMEREPLACE]");
```

Here is my full javascript.

```
@model Cosplay.Models.Projects.CreatePartsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddParts";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        MvcHtmlString emodel = Html.EditorFor(model => Cosplay.Models.Projects.CreatePartModel, "CreatePartModel", "Parts[NAMEREPLACE]");
        string editor = emodel.ToString().Trim().Replace("\"", "\\\"");;
    }
    function getPartHtml(name) {
        var html = '@editor';
        return html.replace("NAMEREPLACE", name);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var lastCount = 5;
        $("#addPartInput").click(function () {
            lastCount++;
            $('#edit_part_list').append(getPartHtml(lastCount));
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="edit_part_list">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Parts)
    </div>

    <a id="addPartInput">Add another part</a><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Edit:
I have fixed problem 2 with the following, but problem 1 is still there.

```
Html.Editor("Parts[X]", "CreatePartModel").ToString().Replace("\"", "\\\"").Replace("\r\n", "\\n");
```

Edit 2:
I have found that the following code will remove all input fields inside the edit model :(

```
Html.Editor("Parts[X]", "CreatePartModel")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<div id="foo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var html = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name).ToHtmlString()))';
$('#foo').html(html);
</script>
```

This way you don't need any replacing. It will also take care of properly encoding.